# Hide button and show after 3 seconds using AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I am just new to AngularJS and would like to ask how to show button after hiding it for 3 seconds when it is clicked.

Please see my code below.

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="showDiv=true" ng-show="!showDiv">Button</button>
```

Thanks

Comment: Try use `$timeout` service

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try use `$timeout` service

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $timeout) {
     $scope.showDiv = true;
    $scope.hide= function(){
         $scope.showDiv = false;
     $timeout(function () {
      $scope.showDiv = true;
    }, 3000);
    }
   
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="hide()" ng-show="showDiv" >Button</button>
</div>
```

Comment: I already got it but anyway, thank for you helped. Really appreciated. A Big Check for you. :)

Answer (score 3):

Use the $timeout service in the controller and use it to unset showDiv.

```
 app.controller('MyController', function ($scope, $timeout) {
    $scope.showDiv = true;
    $scope.enable= function () {
         $scope.showDiv =false; 
         $timeout(function () { $scope.showDiv = true; }, 3000);   
    };


  }
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do this in this way also

```js
angular.module("app",[])
.controller("ctrl",function($scope,$timeout){
$scope.showDiv=false;
$scope.timeout = $timeout;

$scope.saveFun = function(){ 
  $scope.showDiv=true;
}
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
 <button class="btn btn-primary"  ng-show="!showDiv" ng-click="timeout(saveFun,3000);">Save</button>
</div>
```

Comment: I want it to hide directly when the button is clicked and show after 3 seconds

Comment: then use Sajeetharan answer

Answer (score 1):

Try using $timeout this may help you

**JS code**

```
  var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

  app.controller('ctrl', function($scope, $timeout) {
    $scope.hide = false;
    // function
    $scope.hideMe = function() {
      $scope.hide = true;
      var sec = 3000; // 3 seconds
      $timeout(function() {
        $scope.hide = false
      }, sec);
    };

  });
```

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app='myApp'>

  <div ng-controller='ctrl'>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="hideMe()" ng-hide="hide">Button</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is [Jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/wju2zsvL/)